# "Private" struct members in C with const

Tags: c, struct, constants, private

In order to have a clean code, using some OO concept can be useful, even in C.
I often write modules made of a pair of .h and .c files. The problem is that the user of the module have to be careful, since private members don't exist in C. The use of the pimpl idiom or abstract data types is ok, but it adds some code and/or files, and requires a heavier code. I hate using accessor when I don't need one.

Here is a idea which provides a way to make the compiler complain about invalid access to "private" members, with only a few extra code. The idea is to define twice the same structure, but with some extra 'const' added for the user of the module.

Of course, writing in "private" members is still possible with a cast. But the point is only to avoid mistakes from the user of the module, not to safely protect memory.

```
/*** 2DPoint.h module interface ***/
#ifndef H_2D_POINT
#define H_2D_POINT

/* 2D_POINT_IMPL need to be defined in implementation files before #include */
#ifdef 2D_POINT_IMPL
#define _cst_
#else
#define _cst_ const
#endif

typedef struct 2DPoint
{
    /* public members: read and write for user */
    int x;
    
    /* private members: read only for user */
    _cst_ int y;
} 2DPoint;

2DPoint *new_2dPoint(void);
void delete_2dPoint(2DPoint **pt);
void set_y(2DPoint *pt, int newVal);


/*** 2dPoint.c module implementation ***/
#define 2D_POINT_IMPL
#include "2dPoint.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

2DPoint *new_2dPoint(void)
{
    2DPoint *pt = malloc(sizeof(2DPoint));
    pt->x = 42;
    pt->y = 666;

    return pt;
}

void delete_2dPoint(2DPoint **pt)
{
    free(*pt);
    *pt = NULL;
}

void set_y(2DPoint *pt, int newVal)
{
    pt->y = newVal;
}

#endif /* H_2D_POINT */


/*** main.c user's file ***/
#include "2dPoint.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    2DPoint *pt = new_2dPoint();

    pt->x = 10;     /* ok */
    pt->y = 20;     /* Invalid access, y is "private" */    
    set_y(pt, 30);  /* accessor needed */
    printf("pt.x = %d, pt.y = %d\n", pt->x, pt->y);  /* no accessor needed for reading "private" members */

    delete_2dPoint(&pt);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And now, here is the question: is this trick OK with the C standard?
It works fine with GCC, and the compiler doesn't complain about anything, even with some strict flags, but how can I be sure that this is really OK?

Comment: Interesting approach. Whether it's well-defined behaviour I don't know. I'd recommend against it because it's far from idiomatic C... either use an opaque struct (defined in the `.c` file) and provide accessors, or document that fields aren't to be assigned to.

Comment: I think Thomas answer should go as a "real" answer - perhaps with a couple of examples.

Comment: How does `2DPoint` form a valid identifier, by the way?

Comment: I elaborated on Thomas' answer (accidentally, didn't see the comment) under H2CO3's answer, if you want a better idea of how opaque structs work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This violates C 2011 6.2.7 1.

6.2.7 1 requires that two definitions of the same structure in different translation units have compatible type. It is not permitted to have `const` in one and not the other.

In one module, you may have a reference to one of these objects, and the members appear to be const to the compiler. When the compiler writes calls to functions in other modules, it may hold values from the const members in registers or other cache or in partially or fully evaluated expressions from later in the source code than the function call. Then, when the function modifies the member and returns, the original module will not have the changed value. Worse, it may use some combination of the changed value and the old value.

This is highly improper programming.

Comment: @H2CO3, can you explain a bit better. Contrary to your answer, this one here give a correct answer, including a reference to standard that  shows why this is UB.

Comment: @JensGustedt Have a look at the edit. Originally Eric provided an answer regarding C++. Since then he deleted his comments and edited his answer. I have deleted my now-obsolete comment as well.

Comment: @H2CO3, even if previously this was an answer for C++, the ideas about this seem to be similar in the two languages, only the wording is different. In any case, now this answer here uses the correct wording, and it gives a good motivation, not only why this is UB, but also why these two different types may really have a different layout.

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes, that's why I removed my comment. Previously it was you who were complaining about wording, so let's not continue this pointless discussion. I was right, Eric is also right, you don't badger anyone anymore and there'll be peace. Bye.

Answer (score 7):

This is almost certainly undefined behavior.

Writing/modifying an object declared as `const` is prohibited and doing so results in UB. Furthermore, the approach you take re-declares `struct 2DPoint` as two technically different types, which is also not permitted.

Note that this (as undefined behavior in general) does not mean that it "certainly won't work" or "it must crash". In fact, I find it quite **logical that it works,** because if one reads the source intelligently, he may easily find out what the purpose of it is and why it migh be regarded as correct. However, the compiler is not intelligent - at best, it's a finite automaton which has no knowledge about what the code is **supposed** to do; it only obeys (more or less) to the syntactical and semantical rules of the grammar.

Comment: This is *certainly* undefined behavior (not almost) ;)

Comment: Apple is fond of opaque types for this purpose. They'll have `typedef struct Foo *FooRef;` in a header, functions that take or return a `FooRef`, and then the definition of `struct Foo` in the implementation before those functions. Effectively, no public members in the struct, and everything's done through those functions (`FooRef FooCreateWithWidget(WidgetRef w)`, `GrommetRef FooGetGrommet(FooRef foo)`, etc.)

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan But then structs are not typedeffed to `const`, so that's not UB.

Comment: @H2CO3: No, I know--I was saying this is an alternate approach to this common C problem that avoids the constness issue. Replying to your answer may have been the wrong place to mention it though.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan Ah, OK, sorry for the misunderstanding. Yes, that's right.

Comment: @EricPostpischil We are talking about C.

Comment: Same question for C. The code in question does not modify an identifier declared const. It modifies an object declared without const that has been improperly linked to a type in which an object is const.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, that's correct, but from the point of view od the other file that member is still const.

Comment: Why the **HELL** are you downvoting this?

Comment: @H2CO3, it wasn't me but was tempted, too. Your answer is just imprecise on the border of being false. "Identifiers" in C certainly don't have a type or can be `const`-qualified. Objects have a type, that can be `const` qualified, and it is UB to access such an object of `const`-qualified type. So this rule alone wouldn't make the approach in the question UB. Eric is giving the correct answer.

Comment: @JensGustedt I updated the answer to use proper terminology. But: since the object is const qualified **and** it is accessed, that's what invokes UB.

Comment: @H2CO3 wrong. The type of the object is determined in the compilation unit where there is no `const`, so the type of the object is not `const`-qualified. So it is valid to pass such an object back into that compilation unit to modify it. To say it again, your idea why this would be UB was wrong, Eric gave the correct answer and your's is now copying that, without giving reference to Eric's.

Comment: @JensGustedt What are you talking about? Are you accusing me of plagiarism? For changing ONE word for the sake of terminology which **you** were complaining about? Leave me alone now...

Comment: @H2CO3: There is no such thing in the C standard as a const-qualified object. There are const-qualified types. There is a rule against accessing an object defined with a const-qualified type with an lvalue of non-const-qualified type, but that would not apply here since the object would be defined with the non-const type, and the const type would only be used for access. Cite the exact rule in C that is violated.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Maybe it's unclear, but I'm saying the same what you stated in your answer. I'm specifically referring to the "wo definitions of the same structure in different translation units have compatible type" part.

Comment: [Corrected typo.] @H2CO3: Are you retracting your statement that “since the object is const qualified and it is [modified], that's what invokes UB”? Because the object is not const-qualified (since there is no such thing), and the object is not defined by a const-qualified type, so modifying it is not by itself undefined behavior. If you are not retracting it, please state the specific clause of the C standard that is violated.

Answer (score 0):

In Bjarne Stroustrup's words: C is not designed to *support* OOP, although it *enables* OOP, which means it is possible to write OOP programs in C, but only very hard to do so. As such, if you *have to* write OOP code in C, there seems nothing wrong with using this approach,  but it is preferable to use a language better suited for the purpose.

By trying to write OOP code in C, you have already entered a territory where "common sense" has to be overridden, so this approach is fine as long as you take responsibility to use it properly. You also need to ensure that it is thoroughly and rigourously documented and everyone concerned with the code is aware of it.

**Edit** Oh, you may have to use a cast to get around the `const`. I fail to recall if the C-style cast can be used like C++ `const_cast`.

Comment: Writing to an object which constness has been cast away is UB anyway.

Comment: Oh, I see. I seemed to recall having read that constness can be safely cast away, but I am perhaps mistaken. I will look that up again. Thanks.

Comment: Ah I see the problem. I *thought* the question was about if this approach could be used. I overlooked the part about whether it is safe with other compilers than gcc. Sorry about that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use different approach - declare two `struct`s, one for user without private members (in header) and one with private members for internal use in your implementation unit. All private members should be placed after public ones.

You always pass around the pointer to the `struct` and cast it to internal-use when needed, like this:

```
/* user code */
struct foo {
    int public;
};

int bar(void) {
    struct foo *foo = new_foo();
    foo->public = 10;
}

/* implementation */
struct foo_internal {
    int public;
    int private;
};

struct foo *new_foo(void) {
    struct foo_internal *foo == malloc(sizeof(*foo));
    foo->public = 1;
    foo->private = 2;
    return (struct foo*)foo;  // to suppress warning
}
```

C11 allows [unnamed structure fields](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html) (GCC supports it some time), so in case of using GCC (or C11 compliant compiler) you can declare internal structure as:

```
struct foo_internal {
    struct foo;
    int private;
};
```

therefore no extra effort required to keep structure definitions in sync.

Comment: This does not implement the feature that “non-friends” of the class can read, but not write, members.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Agreed, but you can use setters/getters for it. I think it the closest one can get, therefore no reason to downvote

Comment: The question indicates accessors are to be avoided: “I hate using accessor when I don't need one.” This answer does not solve the problem posed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil My answer doesn't solve the problem indeed, but this problem cannot be solved, therefore I've offered the closest possible solution