# Are you allowed to modify a C value that claims to be const if you know for sure that it actually isn't constant?

Tags: c, struct

I came across older code in a project that declares a `struct` in the H file as

```
struct A {
    const int i;  
};
```

Now the function that creates struct A pointers internally looks like this

```
struct A * newStructA ( int i ) {
    struct B * ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct B));
    ptr->i = i;
    return (struct A *)ptr;
}
```

and `struct B` is declared in the C file and looks like this:

```
struct B {
    int i; 
};
```

**Question 1:** Is that even allowed according to C standard? Sure, the data type of `i` is the same and the `struct` should have the same memory layout, but is that guaranteed or could the `const` modifier also change the memory layout on certain systems?

**Question 2:** Knowing that all `struct A *` pointers the code deals with are in fact `struct B *` pointers, would it be allowed to cast the pointers back to `struct B *` and then modify the `int` value? The declaration says it is `const`, but I know for sure that it isn't as it's always located in modifiable heap memory. Or could that have implications as the C compiler may rely on the value being constant, so it assumes it cannot ever change and thus if two lines of code contain `ptr->i` the compiler may not even fetch the value a second time as how could it have changed if it is `const`? As that would lead to very hard to trace bugs that may only be seen if a certain optimization level is being used.

**Question 3:** Is there a better way to achieve a `const` value that external code cannot directly change (or at least should never try to), yet internal code can change as the value is in fact not `const` at all? The only way I can think of would be to hide the struct layout altogether (`struct A;`) but then I need to provide a function like `int getI(struct A * ptr)` and always access the value using that function.

Comment: Shouldn't this be 3 questions? Or two?

Comment: Why does `struct A` exist at all? Since A and B are not compatible types, you shouldn't be accessing B through A in the first place.

Comment: Possibly 'better' code for your `newStructA` function (without the dodgy cast) is: `struct A temp = { i }; struct A* ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct A)); memcpy(ptr, &temp, sizeof(struct A)); return ptr;`. Or you could pass the address of a compound literal to `memcpy` and do away with the `temp` variable: `memcpy(ptr, &((struct A) { i }), sizeof(struct A));`.

Comment: @KamilCuk But then I would have to duplicate everything about the questions three times in three different questions and thus create questions that are 80% dupes of each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are you allowed to modify a C value that claims to be const if you know for sure that it actually isn't constant?

Yes.

> Is that even allowed according to C standard?

Yes.

> is that guaranteed or could the const modifier also change the memory layout on certain systems?

It could, when *defining* the variable as const the variable will typically be placed in a different memory region that is read-only.

> Knowing that all struct A * pointers the code deals with are in fact struct B * pointers, would it be allowed to cast the pointers back to struct B * and then modify the int value?

It is unclear. [Can you safely cast a C structure with non-const members to an equivalent structure with const members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52546353/can-you-safely-cast-a-c-structure-with-non-const-members-to-an-equivalent-struct)

> Or could that have implications as the C compiler may rely on the value being constant, so it assumes it cannot ever change and thus if two lines of code contain ptr->i the compiler may not even fetch the value a second time as how could it have changed if it is const?

Yes. Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/20707255/9072753 .

> Is there a better way to achieve a const value that external code cannot directly change (or at least should never try to), yet internal code can change as the value is in fact not const at all?

This is C. The spirit of C says https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2086.htm :

```
(1) Trust the programmer.
(2) Don't prevent the programmer from doing what needs to be done.
```

In my opinion, a better way is not to hide and just use struct with non-const members. A C programmer will be able to access it anyway.

> The only way I can think of would be to hide the struct layout altogether (struct A;) but then I need to provide a function like int getI(struct A * ptr)

Yes, hiding something will cause runtime overhead. `FILE *` has been with us since forever, and the members of FILE *are* visible to user code in many implementations. Yet no one uses them.

To achieve that a value should not be changed by external code, write a specification of your library that external code should not do it.

To hide your proprietary code, use accessors and let users operate only on pointers to your data with PIMPL idiom.

Comment: Well, "Trust the programmer" is "outdated" according to C11 and the link you provided ;-) And considering that 99.9999% of all mistakes are caused by the programmer (not the compiler, interpreter, or hardware), anything that can prevent mistakes in the first place is probably a good thing. After all, as you pointed out, it won't stop programmers from doing something intentionally, it just will stop them from doing it accidentally.

Answer (score -1):

[C 2011 draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> 6.7.3 Type qualiﬁers ... 6 If an attempt is made to modify an object deﬁned with a const-qualiﬁed type through use of an lvalue with
> non-const-qualiﬁed type, **the behavior is undeﬁned**. If an attempt is
> made to refer to an object deﬁned with a volatile-qualiﬁed type
> through use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualiﬁed type, the behavior
> is undeﬁned.133) 133) This applies to those objects that behave as if
> they were deﬁned with qualiﬁed types, even if they are never actually
> deﬁned as objects in the program (such as an object at a memory-mapped
> input/output address).

Comment: I don't think this applies as object gained it's effective type through assignment of non-const type.

Comment: `modify an object deﬁned` What object? Where was it defined? _When_ was it defined?